# Not able to assign data value returned from api to class variable in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

I am calling api to get data on ngOnInit. However I am not able to assign the data class variable.
Below is the related code

```
  tasks: Task[];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.apiService.getTasks()
      .subscribe( data => {
        Object.keys(data).map((index) => {
          this.tasks.push(data[index]);
       });
      });

  }
```

I get error saying 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' for statement

```
this.tasks.push(data[index]);
```

But the tasks is already defined as array.

Can anyone help me here, the scope really confuses me

Comment: You should declare an empty array `tasks: Task[] = []`

Comment: Thank you @SameerKhan, How could I not see that, Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you do in the map is to return the value of the property, you could use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
this.apiService.getTasks().subscribe(data => {
  this.tasks = Object.values(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Map will return a new array so no need of pushing inside map. Hence Your code should be

```
this.apiService.getTasks()
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.tasks = Object.keys(data).map((index) => {
         return data[index];
         });
      });
```